# How do i implement limiting the rate of access to REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a controller class , need to response back with status code of "429" if too many requests raised.
For example, one second have only one request to take. If more than requests are coming then send a response as 429.
I used below link for reference. I am not getting any idea.
https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter

Is there any possiblity to do in spring boot? How do i test for that scenario?

Is it good idea to mainatin rate limiter in my application?

Note: My application is independent of users to access

Comment: A solution would be to use a HttpFilter mapped on the same url as the controller and in the filter count the number of incoming requests per time interval you need to limit and if the number of requests is higher than the limit respond with the 429, once the time interval has passed reset the counter

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or not depends on what and why you're trying to create limit requests.  For example, if you're trying to reduce traffic to your app server, then you should be doing it at the load balancer or the web server layer.  

If it's for monetization/SLAs, then depending on your web server or load balancer you might have to do it in your code. Ideally, keeping that out of your code would be ideal, or at least separating it.  e.g. if you were using AWS you could put that check in a Lambda@Edge function.

If you're going to do it in your app, I agree with @ValentinCarnu

Comment: @Valentin Carnu, Colud you give simple example or suggest some blogs on it. How to do it in spring boot? Thank you

Comment: @Sriram I'm not sure which details are of most interest for you. As a solution for this use case requires quite some code I can only list the steps and point to some examples which I think are relevant. 
(1) Implement a HTTP Filter (see step 4 for details about how to)
(2) In the filter use a cache to store the counter [How to configure Guava cache](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache)
(3) In the filter check the counter and if the counter is less than max number of calls respond with 429
(4) register a filter with spring boot [How to](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

Comment: @Valentin Carnu, Its worked, i also used RateLimit.create(3) with tryAcquire of timeout options. Is it good idea? Thank you for giving above steps

Comment: @Sriram I assume you use the RateLimiter instead of Guava cache, if yes I think is a good approach. If you use both (the RateLimiter and Guava cache) then maybe you can optimize the solution to use only one of them

Comment: @Valentin Carnu Thank You for quick response